# What is the difference between "nofollow" and "noreferrer" link from SEO perspective?

Tags: seo, nofollow, referrer

I want to know the main difference between "nofollow" and "noreferrer" link from SEO perspective.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is that, in theory, `rel="noreferrer"` should not have any SEO impact, while `nofollow` clearly specifies that the link does not endorse in any way the target URL.

`nofollow` was invented by Google back in 2005 in order to fight comment spam in blogs, any URL appearing in the comment section would not pass PR to the target webpage.

`rel="noreferrer"` mainly affects analytics, how did this visit landed to this page? where comes it from? `noreferrer` specifies to hide that kind of information.

I said **in theory** because there is currently no official documentation that explicitly indicates using `noreferrer` would change anything in SEO terms, but it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

"nofollow" is used by Google, to specify that the Google search spider should not follow that link
"Noreferrer":
Specifies that the browser should not send a HTTP referrer header if the user follows the hyperlink

Comment: I believe that is correct, however it doesn't completely answer the question.   How do each of those effect SEO?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ~ don't believe that referrer has any impact on SEO, since the usage is intended mainly for privacy and security... I mean why would it? its the same as SSL doesn't refer but none the less Google still rewards external links from and to SSL enabled sites.

Answer (score -3):

rel="noreferrer" does not affect anything special. It is effected on the 
 browser side.But in the case of rel="nofollow". The google bot does not check that link.
This is the main difference between this two options.

Comment: "not affect anything special" -- How is not sending a referrer on click nothing special?

Comment: Absolutely what Stephen said. Not receiving referrer information is a major problem for those doing SEO.

Comment: No referer doesn't send the referring URL to the page in the link. It might be very useful when linking from a private page. Let's say you link to site X from example.com/my-secret-url/ you might consider adding no referer to your link. However, this is done browser side and some browsers might ignore that directive, while major browsers comply.