# What is meaning of "nofollow me noreferrer" in a rel attribute of a link?

Tags: nofollow, hyperlink, rel

Recently I was checking the source code of a website. I was expecting the links to do follow or no follow but what I observed was this:

```html
<a href="http://www.website.com" rel="nofollow me noreferrer">
```

What is the meaning of this full line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rel attribute can contain multiple value. [Here is reference link.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel)

> The value of this attribute is a space-separated list of link types.

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" rel="nofollow"/>
<a href="http://www.website.com" rel="me"/>
<a href="http://www.website.com" rel="noreferrer"/>
```

So the short form is

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" rel="nofollow me noreferrer"/>
```

[Nofollow](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) is used when you don't want to pass Google trust factor(Pagerank and Anchor text) to that link.

[Noreferrer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/101864/58259) is used when you want to hide your HTTP referral information, so other sites who use analytics tool don't know from where the traffic is coming.

[Me](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me) is used when you want to reference your profile on any page. It can be anything like google plus, facebook, twitter and [site/author profile](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1229920) as well.