# Do “noopener noreferrer” links count as backlinks?

Tags: seo, backlinks, rel

I have bought ad links in some websites with a link, but when I saw the sites, they add an attribute `noopener noreferrer` on my website link.

Does Google count this as backlink?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Be worried... that your links do not use nofollow*

Personally I'd be more worried about the fact they do not use `rel="nofollow"`, [paid links must use nofollow](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en&visit_id=1-636377253140564918-1327379083&rd=1) otherwise your going to feel the full wrath of [Google's Penguin](http://searchengineland.com/library/google/google-penguin-update).

*Google Search Console is not Realtime*

Google Search Console can take several weeks to months to update the data within your Dashboard, particularly backlinks.

*Google does not reveal all links to your sites... purposely.*

The information provided in the link area of the dashboard is only a snippet of your real link profile, [Google purposely do not display all backlinks](https://moz.com/community/q/google-webmaster-tools-not-displaying-all-backlinks) for one reason and more. Small sites with lesser links will display less links than a big site with many links.

*Backlinks take time... to be discovered*

Often paid links will appear on sites with thousands, or hundreds of thousands of pages and unless your paid link is on the front page, [it can take several weeks](https://moz.com/community/q/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-links-indexed), even months and on some massive sites with no authority, never.

*What is nofollow? noreferrer? and noopener?*

Below you can find various sources with the information that will help you understand what each attribute do.

> Source: [Use rel="nofollow" for specific links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en)
>
> In general, we don't follow them. This means that Google does not
>   transfer PageRank or anchor text across these links. Essentially,
>   using nofollow causes us to drop the target links from our overall
>   graph of the web. However, the target pages may still appear in our
>   index if other sites link to them without using nofollow, or if the
>   URLs are submitted to Google in a Sitemap. Also, it's important to
>   note that other search engines may handle nofollow in slightly
>   different ways.

---

> Source: [What is the difference between “nofollow” and “noreferrer” link from SEO perspective?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/101864/20604)
>
> The difference is that, in theory, `rel="noreferrer"` should not have
>   any SEO impact, while `nofollow` clearly specifies that the link does
>   not endorse in any way the target URL.
>
> `nofollow` was invented by Google back in 2005 in order to fight
>   comment spam in blogs, any URL appearing in the comment section would
>   not pass PR to the target webpage.
>
> `rel="noreferrer"` mainly affects analytics, how did this visit landed
>   to this page? where comes it from? `noreferrer` specifies to hide that
>   kind of information.
>
> I said **in theory** because there is currently no official
>   documentation that explicitly indicates using `noreferral` would
>   change anything in SEO terms, but it shouldn't.

---

> Source: [Opens External Anchors Using rel="noopener"](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener)
>
> When your page links to another page using target="_blank", the new
>   page runs on the same process as your page. If the new page is
>   executing expensive JavaScript, your page's performance may also
>   suffer.
>
> On top of this, target="_blank" is also a security vulnerability. The
>   new page has access to your window object via window.opener, and it
>   can navigate your page to a different URL using window.opener.location
>   = newURL.

You can find out more about these link attributes on [Template Toaster](https://blog.templatetoaster.com/rel-noreferrer-noopener-seo/)

Comment: which is better from your idea nofollow or noopener noreferrer? just for backlink I said

Comment: Nofollow for paid links and sites that have little content relevancy to your own. A few good links is all that is needed, for every time you get a bad link, it takes more good links.

Comment: I read a long story here on simple question,question was - noreferer is dofollow backlink or not buddy?