# Does noreferrer or noopener impact SEO

Tags: seo, html

I was wondering if the html attribute tag noreferrer or noopener had an impact on my google SEO, and if yes, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do “noopener noreferrer” links count as backlinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108428/do-noopener-noreferrer-links-count-as-backlinks)

Comment: @grg. I did search if noreferrer & noopener had an impact on the SEO. didn't find anything in the StackExchange. Then I saw the link you shown me, It does give an answer to my question, but also a lot of information I'm not interested in. Therefore I decided to open a new, more focused, question & then added a nice answer to it because I do think it may help other people like me.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, it **won't have any negative impact on the SEO**.

For more details

#### Noreferrer

Because it prevents passing the referrer information to the target website, this will change the behavior from Google analytic traffic which will show the link as `Direct Traffic` instead of `Referral` from some website.

#### Noopener

Have no impact at all, should always be used on external links.
The noopener is needed to enhance the security of your website and prevent other websites from gaining access to your page (through the browser session)

Comment: @JohnConde Could you give me an explanation on the reason why you did remove the link ?

Comment: We generally remove links for nonauthoritative sources from new users because we're not sure if they're for the purpose of self-promotion or not, which on this site we get a lot of since we cover SEO and marketing. Given that you answered at the same time you posted the question, that might also be considered another indication. However, that doesn't mean that's what you had intended - it's just our standard way of dealing with that.

Comment: If you want to provide a link, next time [add context around the link and quote the most relevant part of it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in case it becomes unreachable. It's also helpful to state your affiliation to it too so that the community doesn't flag it.

Comment: @dan Thx a lot for the explanation. I'm coming from the stackoverflow community where we do provide link if needed, but always like to put every information within the answer for the case the link wont exist anymore. But what you does explain make sense.

Comment: No problem, welcome to the site btw. We'll see next time that you're not a new member, so they'll be less of a concern.